# Vedic Versus that Justify the Difference Between Various Types of Matter

Tags: vedanta, upanishads, dvaita, jivatman

I have been reading the following [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dvaita_Vedanta) page on Dvaita Vedanta and came across the five great differences, two of them being the following:

> > Between matter and jīvātman.

> > Between various types of matter.

What verses in the Vedas and Upanishads and other shastras support these claims?

**PS:** I am neither an Advaitin nor a Dvaitin. I am trying to see and understand the logic and merits of both subschools of Vedanta. Therefore, my intent is not the challenge and "defeat" these particular schools, but I want to see how they respond to each other's arguments.

Comment: - *Between matter and jivatman* - Jivatman is a soul, independent of body, hence matter. This is self evident.

Comment: @AbhasKumarSinha Not according to Advaita who point to the following verses found in Wikipedia page on the Mahavakyas. Furthermore, "atma" can refer to identity and so one can say that Advaita preaches the identity of everything is Brahman.

Comment: sarvam khalv idam brahma - All of this is brahman (Chāndogya Upaniṣad 3.14.1)

Comment: etad vai tat - This, verily, is That (Katha Upanishad)

Comment: @AbhasKumarSinha "This is self evident." How do we know that we see the world as it really is? Only scriptural verses can reveal what reality really is, as per the third verse of the Brahma Sutras. If scriptures give verses that say these differences, then the existence of these differences is worthy of consideration.

Comment: "How do we see the world as it really is?" The world is the same, which appears differently due to ignorance (Advaita). In Davita, the reality of the world is self-established. "World" is an improper word, rather, how consciousness perceives is the correct usage.

Comment: @AbhasKumarSinha Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer here which cites various verses Shri Madhavacharya included in his works on Dvaita Vedanda.

https://adbhutam.wordpress.com/2009/07/20/a-vichara-on-the-paramopanishat-pancha-bheda-prapancha/